# Retrieving the intent values from another class

Tags: android, json

My question is a bit basic. I've been learning to code on JAVA and android. Here I am a bit confused on how to call the values that I have sent via an intent.

In my first activity this is the intent that I am using.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Secondactivity.class);
            String regName1 = regName;
            intent.putExtra(regName1, regNameSplit[0]);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Here regName1 will contain three values. SessionID,URL,Name split by "-".

In my SecondActivity

```
public class Secondactivity extends Activity {
public final String TAG = "###---Secondactivity---###";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);
    Log.i(TAG,"before if statement");
    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("regName1") != null){
        getIntent().getStringExtra("regName1").split("-");
        String[] str = "regName";
        Log.i(TAG, ""+str[0]+str[1]+str[2])
    }
}
```

}

The value if regName1 always comes as null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
intent.putExtra(regName1, regNameSplit[0]);
```

Needs to be like this instead

```
intent.putExtra("regName1", regNameSplit[0]); // note the quotes
```

BUT you are using regName1 as a variable... how do you expect the second class to know that variable?

Use a string resource instead.

Comment: Thanks m8..your help was invaluable

Answer (score 0):

and you are sure that the content of the variable regName is actually "regName"?
cause you set the value using

```
intent.putExtra(regName, ... )
```

and you get the value using

```
intent.getStringExtra("regName")
```

Comment: I made a mistake while typing the question. Could you go through it now. Changed it to call regName1. But yet I get a null value

Answer (score 0):

use firstactivity

dont use

String regname1=regname;

just:
        intent.putExtra("regName1", regNameSplit[0]);

in second Activity

`if (getIntent().getStringExtra("regName1") != null){
//
}`

Comment: I was using                                         (getIntent().getStringExtra("regName1") != null)                      I messed up while writing the question. Could you go through it again.